# How Set This problem " Ad failed to load : 3" i have tried all internet tips

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I have problem in Android Studio with Admob app montization. The test ads show correctly but when I create a signed APK and then install it to a real device the ads do not work.

I get this error with real ads:

> Ad failed to load : 3

I am using this Admob SDK:

```
   compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0')
```

The new version of the SDK also has this error